# A reverse inequality of a hard $n$-variable inequality

Tags: multivariable-calculus, inequality, summation

[In this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4224749/how-to-prove-this-inequality-with-this-sqrtn-leftx-12x-22-dotsx) we solved Cheng Shenli's problem, and recently I found a fact that there might exist a reverse inequality of it. The reverse inequality is as follow: 
$x_i \in \mathbb{R} \quad (i=1,2,\dots,n)$and $n \ge 2$. Prove or deny:
$$
\sum_{c y c} \sqrt{x_{1}^{2}+\frac{\left((n-1) x_{1}-x_{2}-\dots-x_{n}\right)^{2}}{4 (n-1)}} \ge \sqrt{n\left(x_{1}^{2}+x_{2}^{2}+\dots+x_{n}^{2}\right)}
$$
for $n=3$, mma tells it is true. I wonder if anyone can prove or disprove it :blush:

Comment: I think, this inequality is much more harder than the previous one.  We can remove radicals with saving of the equality occurring.  But even for $n=3$ we obtain something very hard. For non-negative variables with $n=3$ it's easier.