# If $x$ exists how to find $x$ such that these inequalities are true .

Tags: inequality

Hi i try to find $x\geq 1$ for $0\leq a,b,c\leq 1$ such that :

$$f\left(x\right)=\frac{3\left(2a-\frac{b+c}{2}+x\right)^{2}}{\left(a+b+c+3x\right)^{2}}\left(a^{2}+b^{2}+c^{2}\right)-\left(a^{2}+\frac{\left(2a-b-c\right)^{2}}{24}\right)\geq 0$$

$$g\left(x\right)=\frac{3\left(2b-\frac{a+c}{2}+x\right)^{2}}{\left(a+b+c+3x\right)^{2}}\left(a^{2}+b^{2}+c^{2}\right)-\left(b^{2}+\frac{\left(2b-a-c\right)^{2}}{24}\right)\geq 0$$

$$h\left(x\right)=\frac{3\left(2c-\frac{b+a}{2}+x\right)^{2}}{\left(a+b+c+3x\right)^{2}}\left(a^{2}+b^{2}+c^{2}\right)-\left(c^{2}+\frac{\left(2c-b-a\right)^{2}}{24}\right)\geq 0$$

Some simulations suggest for $1\geq a\geq b \ge c\geq 0$ and $c\geq a-b$ we can choose $x=x_{root}$ where we have $h(x_{root})=0$ . It suggest also that $x$ not always exits without these constraints.

We can solve the quadratic but it becomes very ugly and not useful in replacing the value of $x$ in $f,g$.

So with the constraints $1\geq a\geq b \ge c\geq 0$ and $c\geq a-b$ can we find a simpler $x$ , and if we can ,find $x$ as an homogeneous expression ?

Edit :

It's related to my answer here [How to prove this inequality with this $\sqrt{n\left(x_{1}^{2}+x_{2}^{2}+\dots+x_{n}^{2}\right)} $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4224749/how-to-prove-this-inequality-with-this-sqrtn-leftx-12x-22-dotsx/4230254#4230254)

Some track :

With the constraints above and provided that $u,v,w\ge \frac{4}{3}$ such that $f(u)=g(v)=h(w)=0$ and $\left(11a+11b-34c-12x\right)\left(a+b-2c\right)=0$ implies $0.75\leq x\leq \frac{4}{3}$ then it seems we can take (as partial answer):

$$\frac{\left(h\left(\frac{4}{3}\right)-h\left(\frac{8}{3}\right)\right)}{\frac{4}{3}-\frac{8}{3}}\left(x-\frac{4}{3}\right)+h\left(\frac{4}{3}\right)= 0$$

Thanks in advance for your effort .

Comment: How did you come up with these particular expressions? Why would it be interesting to find such an $x$? Is this perhaps related to some other question that you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 1):

Alternative approach to solve the problem :

Define :

$$f\left(x\right)=\frac{3\left(2c-\frac{\left(a+b\right)}{2}+x\right)^{2}}{\left(a+b+c+3x\right)^{2}}\left(a^{2}+b^{2}+c^{2}\right)-\left(c^{2}+\frac{\left(2c-a-b\right)^{2}}{24}\right)$$

Now let $0\leq c\leq b\leq a\leq 1 $ such that $c=0.25(a-b)$ and $a\leq 2b$

Then it seems we have the inequalities :

$$\frac{3\left(2a-\frac{\left(b+c\right)}{2}+0.5\left(a+b-4c\right)\right)^{2}}{\left(a+b+c+3\left(0.5\left(a+b-4c\right)\right)\right)^{2}}\left(a^{2}+b^{2}+c^{2}\right)-\left(a^{2}+\frac{\left(2a-b-c\right)^{2}}{24}\right)+\frac{f\left(0.5\left(a+b-4c\right)\right)}{2}\geq 0$$

And :

$$\frac{3\left(2b-\frac{\left(a+c\right)}{2}+0.5\left(a+b-4c\right)\right)^{2}}{\left(a+b+c+3\left(0.5\left(a+b-4c\right)\right)\right)^{2}}\left(a^{2}+b^{2}+c^{2}\right)-\left(b^{2}+\frac{\left(2b-a-c\right)^{2}}{24}\right)+\frac{f\left(0.5\left(a+b-4c\right)\right)}{2}\geq 0$$

Where I used derivative of $f(x)$